# Saving incoming users referring data for later use

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using Google analytics to track our users.
We are running google Adwords and facebook ads campaigns.

Our campaigns mostly focus on bringing users and see if they register to our service.
I want to add an option for us to know which of these converted users transformed into paying users later on from our service.

My idea was to read from the google analytics cookie the connected user's referring data and pass it to the server once the user pays us, but I can't find a way to do so.

The only other way I can think of right now is to develop my own tracking functionalities that will track our incoming users and save for each one of them were they came from for later use.

I'd love to hear if there are better tools\practices or anything else I'm missing.

Thanks

Comment: You are missing that with Universal Analytics there is no referral data in the cookie (that was only true with the previous version that did channel attribution on the client). That's why this approach does not work (the UA cookie only has an anonymized client id).

Comment: Any other recommended tools that filled the void when the new version was released?

Comment: No, not really. That was never a documented feature, so people who used this are out on their own. You can store a unique key for each user (anonymized as not to violate Google's TOS) and then use the API to match this with data from a third party system.  I have an tutorial that deals with a similar problem here: http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/import-ga-information-to-salesforce-part-1/, maybe this will give you some inspiration (this is about GA/Salesforce integration, but a similar approach will work for other applications as long as they have an API).

Comment: You don't have to develop it on your own, there is plenty solution to come up with - like http://www.terminusapp.com/blog/add-utm-referrer-lead-forms/

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the answer and for the alternative - its exactly what I needed.